# Summation with absolute value $\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k}\alpha^{|n-k|}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

How can I calculate explicitly $\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k}\alpha^{|n-k|}$ for every whole number n?
Note that $-1<\alpha<1$

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $|n-k|=n-k$ if $k<n$, and $|n-k|=k-n$ if $k\ge n$.  So
$$\sum_{k=-2}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{k}\alpha^{|n-k|}
  =\sum_{k=-2}^{n-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{k}\alpha^{n-k}
    +\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^{k}\alpha^{k-n}$$
which is a sum of two GPs.  You will have to be careful with the first one if $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, why should i be careful if a=$(\frac{1}{2})$ on the first sum? it is a finite sum of a geometric series

Comment: What is the ratio in the first GP if $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Ratio would be 1 and the sum would be $\frac{1}{2}^{n}(n+2)$

Comment: That's right - different formula when the ratio is $1$.